# Function undefined. Unable to call a function after dynamically loading js file

Tags: javascript

My html file is as follows - a.html

```html
<html>
<head>

<script id="js" type="text/javascript">

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function loadScript(src, cb){
 alert('in');
 //let script = document.getElementById('js');
 let script = document.createElement( "script" )
 script.src = src;
 console.log(document.getElementById('js').src);
 script.onload = cb();
 //myFunc();
 //cb();
 document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0].appendChild( script );
 
 alert('comp');
}

function callb(){
alert('in callb');
myFunc();
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<input type="button" value="Click1" onclick = "loadScript('test.js',callb)"/>

<input type="button" value="Click2" />
</body>

</html>
```

My external js file is  - test.js

```js
function myFunc(){
alert("inside js file");
}
```

When i click the button Click1  I got

alert : in

alert : in callb

and then myFunc is undefined.

Hasnt the appended script tag loaded successfully? Please help me understand where am I going wrong. I am a novice in javascript.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling. In this context how is cb different from cb()?

Comment: `cb` is a reference to the function object. `cb()` calls that function object. You want to assign a function to `script.onload` since you are telling the browser *"call this function when you are done"*. When you use `cb()` you are (in theory) trying to assign the return value of the function to `script.onload`. I.e. you are calling the function *before* the script was loaded and `myFunc` does not exist yet.

Comment: @FelixKling Quick question. What if cb is a function that takes an argument? In such a case how can the argument be passed when calling for script.onload?

Comment: You can simply create and assign another function which calls `cb` with the argument: `script.onload = function() { cb("some argument"); };`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`script.onload = cb();` should be `script.onload = cb;`. The former calls `cb()` *right then and there* and assigns the **return value** to `script.onload`. In other words you are calling the callback *before* the script finished loading, at which point the function `myFunc` doesn't exist yet of course.

Also don't use `alert` for debugging because it's blocking and can verify well impact how your code behaves when dealing with async i/o.

Comment: Many thanks! I replaced all alerts with console.log and I got 'comp' before 'inside js file'